# Landscape Mode Exposes Password

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am running Android 4.2.2 on a Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.4 on a Nexus 5 and Android 4.4 on a Nexus 10 to test.

On the Nexus 10, everything works great.  On the two phones, if I enter a password, then turn the phone into Landscape and the soft-keyboard pops up, it exposes the characters (in this case, numbers only).  (in portrait they are hidden).

My app uses a passcode to enter it.  I have the field set like this:

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPasscode"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:password="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

I know `password="true"` is deprecated.  But from what I understand, if you want to target pre 4.0 devices, then there really is no other way if you want the number pad to show and the numbers to be masked in a password style.  There are many stack questions on that and no real answers other than that from my research.

I am not sure if this setup is causing the landscape bug?

Comment: I am on a 4.1.2 based HTC One, I gave your xml a quick try and everything seems to be working at my end. The password is masked in both landscape and portrait

Comment: Is it possible you have another layout file with the same name in a different resource folder, that does not have password="true"? That might explain why this only happens on some devices.

Comment: @EricSchlenz I checked on this and only one layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same experiences on one particular device where the number/text becomes visible. Use the "numberPassword" as the input type
as apposed to the input type "phone" in your example you posted.

```
....
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:password="true"
....
```

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/password"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:inputType="numberPassword"
  android:maxLength="4"
  android:password="true"
  android:textColor="@android:color/black"
  tools:ignore="Deprecated" />
```